# Split a dataframe into two but knowing already one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coding-style

I have a `dataframe` with one column called "label", which represents a binary feature [0,1].
The dataframe is imbalanced, with more labels 0 than 1s, therefore, to build a good estimator, I want to split the data into training and testing subsets, where the training subset has to be well balanced. I could try using resample algorithms like SMOTE or others; how ever, I decided to go with the following stratergy:

Select all those rows of `dataframe` with the label 1 and make from that a random subselection with the 80%, like:

```
train_class1=dataframe[dataframe["label"]==1].iloc[np.random.randint(0, len(dataframe[dataframe["label"]==1]), len(dataframe[dataframe["label"]==1])*80//100)]
```

Then, from the rows with label 0, I did a random subselection of the same size as `train_class1` and I called it `train_class0`, like:

```
train_class0=dataframe[dataframe["label"]==0].iloc[np.random.randint(0, len(dataframe[dataframe["label"]==0]), len(dataframe[dataframe["label"]==1])*80//100)]
```

So I was planning to concatenate by rows both dataframes to be my training subsample:

```
train_class=pd.concat([train_class1,train_class0])
```

Now, as testing subsample I want it to be the rest of the initial `dataframe`, this is: all those rows of `dataframe` that don't belong to `train_class`. I tried the following:

```
test_class =pd.concat([dataframe, train_class]).drop_duplicates()
```

to concatenate the initial `dataframe` with `train_class` and remove the duplicate rows.

However this looks normal (at least to me at this point), when I check the shapes of `dataframe`, `train_class` and `test_class`, I get:

```
dataframe.shape=(257673, 208)

train_class.shape=(263476, 208)

test_class.shape=(257673, 208)
```

which is obviously contradictory.

What I am doing wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem...

It was in the definition of train_class1 and train_class0, that I changed to:

```
train_class1=dataframe[dataframe["label"]==1].sample(len(dataframe[dataframe["label"]==0])*80//100)
train_class0=dataframe[dataframe["label"]==0].sample(len(dataframe[dataframe["label"]==0])*80//100)
```

by using the built-in pandas function df.sample().